# Oracle APEX JSON.WRITER.NOT_OPEN

Tags: json, oracle, oracle-apex, writer

Oracle APEX 5.1.  I am trying to create a computation that determines the value of a page item.  When I do this, I am pasting in a statement that causes the following error to appear:

```
Error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 5 column 1 of the JSON data
```

If I further try to save it, I get a red inline error:

```
ORA-20987: APEX - JSON.WRITER.NOT_OPEN - Contact your application administrator.
```

[image: Error Here]

This is reproducible each time.

Comment: This looks like a bug in APEX 5.1. Have you tried logging out and loggin in again? Have you tried the same thing in a fresh application? You might need to raise an SR with Oracle. Specify the exact version of APEX and exactly what value you're pasting into what attribute of the computation.

Comment: I think I may have figured out what's going on -- if you paste in a select X into Y statement that is able to execute on the item into the computation, everything breaks.  This can be mitigated by simply doing a select statement.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.
after repeated attempts realised that i got the error when i do a cut-copy/ paste in an sql query. When i type in the lines (instead of cut-copy/paste) i did not get the error.
Try it out and see if the same happens in your case

Comment: Yes, it happened when I copy pasted sql query. But refreshing the page worked for me.